# JSTL SQL Update rowCount?

Tags: mysql, sql, jstl

Is it possible to count the rows affected from an sql update statement inside jstl?

I have tried to do this but it does not work.

Comment: <sql:update var="reqConfirmBooking" scope="page">.  And then i want to run a test to check if the update was successful. I have tried: reqConfirmBooking.rowCount != 1 and another test reqConfirmBooking.rowCount == 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [JSTL TLD Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/), the `var` attribute specifies the name of the variable containing the row count, so as per your example

```
reqConfirmBooking != 0
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you! it worked. My mistake I did not need to add ".rowCount" to the end of the variable as the variable already held the number of rows affected!